# Transform string into number (array size), input of that array and output it back. ASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm, tasm

In this programm i struggle to convert string into number. I have spent around 10 hours with this code already (yeah, I'm a novice) and I have a strong feeling I'm so close to the point when it's gonna work... Please, prove me right or prove me wrong! =) I tried to add as many comments as possible in the most complicated (as for me) parts of the code so you can save your time in case you have a mood to help me out a little. I'll be glad to explaine code even more if neccessary. Sorry for my English and let's see the code.

```
model tiny
   .code
    org 0100h
    start:
       mov ax,cs
       mov ds,ax

       mov dx,offset text
       mov ah,09h
       int 21h

       mov dx,offset x
       mov ah,3fh
       int 21h

       mov dh,byte ptr[x+di]   ; Loading first digit into elem.
       sub dh,48 
       mov ah,2

CH2INT:mov elem,dh

_TEST: push di

OFFST1:mov cl,ah
       dec cl
       add di,di
       loop OFFST1
       mov dh,byte ptr[x+di]   ; Loading next (x+di*2) digit into dh.
       pop di                  ; Inc ah for the next iteration.
       inc ah                  ; Here we see if next char is a digit or not,
       cmp dh,"0"              ; if it is (meaning that current digit isn't in the lowest position) -  
       jb INVAL                ; multiplying current digit by 10 (our base),
       cmp dh,"9"              ; if not - jump to INVAL where we go on to the next digit (if there is any).
       ja INVAL                ; Push-pop ax just for convinience, I'm almost out of free-to-use registers.
       push ax                 
       mov al,elem            
       mov ten,10
       imul ten
       mov elem,al
       pop ax
       jmp _TEST

INVAL: mov al,elem             ; Adding number we got to the sum which in the end (after jump to NEXT) 
       add sum,al              ; will containe inputt size of array as a number, not a char.
       push di

OFFST2:mov cl,ah
       dec cl
       add di,di
       loop OFFST2
       mov dh,byte ptr[x+di]   ; Move next digit into dh (x+ah(wich was incremented earlier)+di).
       pop di                  ; See if there is a next digit in x or previous one was the last one
       cmp dh,"0"              ; (I just hope that next value in memory after the inputt will not be a digit...
       jb NEXT                 ; I understand that it's not nice and a luck game, but I do not yet come up with smthn better).
       cmp dh,"9"              
       ja NEXT
       push di                 ; Next few lines write next char into dh (but with index less by 1 than in previous
                           ; few lines, where we checked is there any more digits in the inputt value left.
OFFST3:mov cl,ah               
       sub cl,2
       add di,di
       loop OFFST3
       mov dh,byte ptr[x+di]
       pop di
       sub dh,48
       jmp CH2INT              ; Jump to next iteration to work with next digit in the inputt value

NEXT:  mov dx,offset array
       mov ah,3fh
       int 21h
       mov cl,sum

L:     mov dh,byte ptr[array+di]
       inc di
       mov dl,dh
       mov ah,02h
       int 21h
       loop L

       mov ah,4Ch              ; Service 4Ch - Terminate with Error Code
       mov al,0                ; Error code
       int 21h                 ; Interrupt 21h - DOS General Interrupts

     ret

     array db 256 dup (?)      ; Array
     x     db ?                ; Size of the array
     ten   db ?
     text  db "Enter number of elements in array: $"
     elem  db ?                ; A single digit from the inputt value  
     sum   db 0                ; Inputt value transformed into number

     end start
```

Code written in TASM as a .com executable. It has some irrational things here and there but it's just for the clarity and due to the fact it's just a draft. Hugely appreciate your help! Thanks!

P.S. I'll be modifying the code over time in case you'll give me some advise.

Comment: Is this [INT21/AH=3f](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm) you are using at the very beginning of your code?

Comment: Yeah... It worked in my other programms well, so here it is. Or should I use ah=0ah instead?

Comment: You can use it but you have to properly set input register and the buffer. `BX` and `CX` are not set and the buffer at `x` is 1 byte long. There are other things that look "strange" as well at first sight, are you sure you are *close* to a working program? Have you done some debugging?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, sadly. I'll try to do smthn about setting input registers, thanks! Do you suggest me change x to word? If you don't mind, can you please point to me these "strange" things? As for debugging, I'm trying to use TD, but I'm not totally understand it, so it's not much of a help for me.

Comment: The buffer must be large enough to hold all the data read from the user. Since you want a decimal number you can have at most 10 digits for 32 bits number and 5 digits for 16 bits number, so 11 or 6 bytes will do depending on the size you are working with. Initialize the buffer with 0s so the read string is automatically null terminated.

Comment: For the other things, please note I haven't reviewed your code carefully, just a quick look. `di` is not initialized, the `add di, di` for indexing the string seems wrong, the multiplication by `ten` is over complicated (why a memory operand?), the `_TEST` loop seems never ending. Rectification of the comment above: It seems you want to read a 2 digit decimal number, so a 2 byte buffer will do

Comment: OK, should be useful! Can I ask you one more time to make a comment on how I handle indexing in lines like mov dh,byte ptr[x+di]

Comment: You named your buffer `x` and you know you have only two digits, so the first one is `[x]` the second one is `[x+1]`. Beware that by using the 3fh service you may end up with a CR char in the buffer if the user input one digit and press return. To be honest it will be easier to just restart from scratch rather than fixing the existing code :). Never copy paste code in assembly as it is highly context specific (read: it will not work) unless it is a standalone function. Split the problem into subproblems (get the string, convert to number, ...) and if you have trouble you can ask new questions

Comment: Well, you must be right=) I'll better start from scratch. By the way, not a single string here is copy-pasted) It don't change the fact the code isn't working thow... OK, thank you for help!)

Comment: Don't forget to ask here if you need help ;)